# Flex-box align navigation items to sidebar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On a simple flex-box layout, I am trying to align nav items to the end of the first (left) side-bar. My first thought was to recreate the `aside main aside` layout with `:before element :after` so the nav items would always align to the sidebar, but I can't seem to get the `:before` and `:after` elements to match the size of each `aside`. Here is an example of what I am trying to do
[Flex Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKpKv.png)

And here is the current code I am using

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoJEbX?editors=010

Comment: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Comment: Why did my question get down voted? Did I do something wrong when asking?

Comment: Unless the downvoter tells you why he/she cast the vote, you never really know. However, to minimize your chances of getting downvoted, familiarize yourself with the question guidelines. See [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't be using flex-wrapping rows here. It makes sense to start with `flex-direction:column` to get the full 100% height and then put the middle content (`main` and `aside` elements) in their own flex-container which can then grow as much as is required.

The horizontal layout is all flexbox.

Based on the original code the `aside` are 1/12th wide each (`flex:1`) while the `main` is 10/12ths (`flex:10`).

Therefore to line up the menu with the `main`, the menu itself needs to be shifted over the same amount (which means it's 11/12ths [`flex:11`] so the pseudo-element is just `flex:1`.

*Adjust as required.*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
}
nav:before {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  background: plum;
  /* for reference */
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex: 11;
}
nav ul a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px 0 0;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
main {
  background: red;
  flex: 10;
}
aside {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}
footer {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    <aside>Sidebar 1</aside>
    <main>Main Content Area</main>
    <aside>Sidebar 2</aside>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gPpKMa)